# Does Uber API run on Cordova/Ionic/Web Application

Tags: uber-api

Does Uber API support hybrid application(Cordova/Ionic) and Web Applicatio? Or only on Android and iOS devices

Answer (score 1):

Since Uber API’s can communicate using various cross-platform solutions by using HTTP calls and Cordova/Ionic is JavaScript based platform, I am pretty sure that you can implement API calls by using your platform, although there is no official support for that.

Please check official documentation for other platforms which can be found [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/introduction).

All the best,